Issues uploading images from Linux to an HTML site
I am trying to upload images to my HTML site from Linux Ubuntu, but when I do there are no file extensions. How can I get the file extensions to upload?
When I run a ls on the folder it shows:

All the images, but only the .jpg files have any extension at all.  This is also what is sent to the HTML site.
How can I get the file extensions so I can do data validation (making sure the file trying to be uploaded is an image)?

Seems the files were created without an extension.  What are you using to create them?  But really, content validation like @grawity_u1686 mentions is much better than using file extensions which can be set to anything, regardless of what the actual content of the file is.

Validate by content, not by name. All popular image formats have very recognizable headers, so you can use tools such as file to determine each file's type before upload (and then manually rename the files to add appropriate extensions), or if you're writing a webapp that accepts uploads itself, use a library that does the same thing, e.g. libmagic or PHP's fileinfo. (Many image handling libraries themselves can do the job as well.)
$ file dogs
dogs: PNG image data, 1920 x 1080, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced

$ mv dogs dogs.png

$ file Audrey
Audrey: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, [...], 1388x2048

$ mv Audrey Audrey.jpg

Webservers sometimes have similar features built in, e.g. Apache httpd has mod_mime_magic which will automatically determine the Content-Type to send in HTTP headers without relying on the file extension.
